# moving from machd to mac os lion 10.75

Tags: software-update

how do i update my macbook air Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5  to a more up to date version as I need to install remote access. When I try currently it says
Microsoft Remote Desktop can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because Mac OS X version 10.9 or later is required.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Mac App Store, then click on the updates tab and download & install the latest update

Comment: The earliest Airs can't use anything newer than 10.7.5

Comment: @Tetsujin well he never says anything about which version he has, and I was only trying to add basic help. If the OP could provide us with more info, that'd be helpful.

Comment: then really it ought to be a comment until a full answer can be established. Request further info to formulate an answer that will survive the test of time & google.